# cakephp - error when trying to use Cake Console

Tags: cakephp, terminal

i'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap in my Cakephp. Thus i follow the tutorial given here>>https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap.
When i try to run the command

```
Console/cake TwitterBootstrap.copy
```

this is what turns out:

```
kostas@ubuntu-laptop:~/Desktop/Projects/mailer/app$ Console/cake TwitterBootstrap.copy
Error: Shell class CopyShell could not be found.
#0 /home/kostas/Desktop/Projects/mailer/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(190): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('TwitterBootstra...')
#1 /home/kostas/Desktop/Projects/mailer/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(68): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /home/kostas/Desktop/Projects/mailer/app/Console/cake.php(37): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
kostas@ubuntu-laptop:~/Desktop/Projects/mailer/app$
```

Do you know what's happening? :/ I have been trying to bypass this problem for a while without having found any solution yet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you folder `Console` is the exact same as the link you provided?

Comment: Yes it is the exact same.

Comment: Did you enable the plugin as documented? Also ALWAYS mention the exact cakePHP version you are using.

Comment: yes i enabled it and did exactly what the tutorial said before this line i have the problem! My cakephp version is the latest (2.3.5).

Comment: These kind of errors almost always boil down to a file/folder being misnamed. Check the file `~/Desktop/Projects/mailer/app/Plugin/TwitterBootstrap/Console/Command/CopyShell.php` really does exist; since it's not a missing-plugin error the plugin is (allegedly) registered; as a last resort do some logging/debugging [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.5/lib/Cake/Core/App.php#L558) to find where the error/difference is.